# Bigger outer chanring for Shimano FC-M4100-2

Tags: crankset, chainring, gearing

I'm trying to find a way to put on a bigger outer chainring on my FC-M4100-2 crankset. It's 26/36T and I would like to have 26/42T.

It's 96 bcd but I cannot find any rings. Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question in favor of discussing it under the other question you asked.

Comment: Yes, lets close it. If someone later finds it I think the 40T-AX 40t chainring would at least fit. Not sure if it will work good or not though.